Maximal number of acute triangles for $n$ lines
I have just come across an old but very interesting old post, about the acute triangles formed by points , i.e.  Maximum number of acute triangles.
Now I wonder the similar results for lines: suppose we have $n$ lines on the plane, and we want to find the maximal number of acute triangles formed by these $n$ lines. What is the best result / estimation we can have?
And a follow up question: what is the maximal number of obtuse triangles?
I tried some small cases, and find out that this problem is not that easy. An observation might be useful is that for any 4 lines in general position, there could be exactly 2 acute triangles and 2 obtuse triangles.

What do you mean for lines to form triangles? The boundary of the triangle is contained in some three lines?

For any three lines L1, L2, L3, the triangle they form is the unique triangle whose three vertices are the intersection of L1 and L2, L1 and L3, L2 and L3

This is not a full answer, but a couple of observations. We can get a lower bound from the configuration given by a triangular tiling (see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleTiling.html). This gives a configuration of $n=3k$ lines, with at least
$$
N(k) =  \begin{cases}\frac{1}{8} k(k+2)(2 k+1) & \text { for } k \text { even } \\ \frac{1}{8}[k(k+2)(2 k+1)-1] & \text { for } k \text { odd }\end{cases}
$$
acute triangles, noting that in fact all triangles are equilateral. Analyzing this slightly more carefully, we see that we get strictly more triangles, since the above comes from line segments, and not lines. Extending the line segments in these tilings to lines, I believe we obtain for $k=3$, $20$ acute triangles, whereas $N(3) = 13$, and for $k=4$, we get $42$, whereas $N(4) = 36$. You could try to find a closed form expression for the number of triangles formed this way. I would boldly conjecture that this construction maximizes the number of acute triangles.
Since $N(k)\in \Theta(k^3)$, and $n=3k$, asymptotically we can get a cubic number of acute triangles in terms of $n$. This is best possible (ignoring constants), since $\binom{n}{3}$ is a trivial upper bound.
